# angular + bootstrap showing and hiding while preserving layout

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a good way to add and remove elements without reflowing the page and causing all the elements to jitter about?

The angular directives `ng-show` and `ng-hide` don't preserve layout.

and [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-show-hide) classes don't either

```
<div class="show">...</div>
<div class="hidden">...</div>
```

Is there a good way to add and remove elements without reflowing the page and causing all the elements to jitter about?

Comment: look into css transitions.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-hide` and `ng-show` uses `display:none`

You need to add new property in CSS for `visibility : hidden`

```
 .element-hidden{
     visibility: hidden;
  }
```

And then provide the condition to ng directive - `ng-class`

e.g.

```
ng-class="{element-hidden : hideBox == true}"
```

where `hideBox == true` is the condition you want to check..

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the CSS `visibility` attribute which makes an item invisible, but still allows the element to take up space on the DOM.  There's no built-in Angular directive which will do this so you'll need to roll your own.

```
myApp.directive("visiblityOn", function(){
    return{
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element){
            scope.$watch('visibilityFlag', function(){
                element[0].style.visibility = scope.visibilityFlag ? "visible" : "hidden";
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and a corresponding controller that will work with your directive:

```
myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){

    $scope.visibilityFlag = true;

    $scope.changeVisibility = function(){
        $scope.visibilityFlag = !$scope.visibilityFlag;
    };

});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bLwmmq34/1/)

Comment: without isolate scope this directive is not reusable

Answer (score -1):

@RahulPatil's answer is correct but somewhat inelegant. I would suggest to keep using `ng-show`/`ng-hide` because it's easier and more readable (i.e. keeps using the same pattern), and add an override in CSS for you particular items:

```
.keepInFlow.ng-hide {
   dislpay: block!important;
   visibility: hidden;
}

<div class="keepInFlow" ng-show="show">..</div>
```

Angular's [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow#overriding-ng-hide-) also mentions overriding `ng-hide`

Comment: Absolutely, but sometimes, you just want to hide partial elements in an application and not change APP WIDE behavior. That's why I suggested that solution :-)

Comment: It's not app-wide. It's prefixed with a custom class, so it applies only to those elements that you chose.